# How to test Artifactory DB connection

Tags: sql-server, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have set Jfrog Artifactory to connect to a SQL server DB. 
Now, i want to test this connection to see if it works.

How can i test this connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start Artifactory and see that it connect to it. What other test do you want to do? Another option will be to download app as DBvisualizer and connect it using the same url and port + user and password as you configured in Artifactory